# Yii: Show Database records in UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, pagination, yii, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to load a list of records into a jQuery UI Dialog with a ajax-call. Here i would need a working ajax pagination. I tryed 'zii.widgets.CListView', but could not get it to work properly. Do i have to write the List/Pagination all by my self or is there a easy solution?

As i am not a big fan of the yii-jQuery functions, i handle the Dialog and the ajax call by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to write anything yourself to get the default functions working. There are number of optional attributes you can define to change the way it renders, see:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView

You can further change the way it looks via basic CSS.

Which part isn't working for you?

One thing you can try is to use the Gii tools and have Yii create the CRUD files for you and then you can modify or use that output as a guide.

Comment: My problem was, that the ajax-pagination of the ClistView didn't work after it is loaded via ajax call into a jQuery UI Dialog. But somehow it works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool. You might want to make sure the jquery library isn't loading twice if you are using it on your own -- a common issue since Yii will dynamically load it's own version.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I let yii load the library, but i don't let it build the functions...